# How the usort() sorting algorithm works?

Tags: php, quicksort, usort

I have an usort() example and I added some echo statements to see how the code works:

```
<?php
function list_cmp($a, $b) {
    global $order;
    echo "\$a=$a, \$b=$b </br>";

    foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
        echo "\$value=$value </br>";
        if ($a == $value) {
            echo "\$a=\$value, returing 0. </br>";
            return 0;
        }
        if ($b == $value) {
            echo "\$b=\$value, returing 1. </br>";
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

$order[0] = 1;
$order[1] = 3;
$order[2] = 4;
$order[3] = 2;

$array[0] = 2;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4;
$array[4] = 2;
array[5] = 1;
$array[6] = 2;

usort($array, "list_cmp");
?>
```

The output of the code is this:

```
$a=2, $b=1 
$value=1 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=2, $b=3 
$value=1 
$value=3 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=1, $b=3 
$value=1 
$a=$value, returing 0. 
$a=2, $b=4 
$value=1 
$value=3 
$value=4 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=3, $b=4 
$value=1 
$value=3 
$a=$value, returing 0. 
$a=2, $b=2 
$value=1 
$value=3 
$value=4 
$value=2 
$a=$value, returing 0. 
$a=2, $b=1 
$value=1 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=2, $b=1 
$value=1 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=4, $b=1 
$value=1 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=3, $b=1 
$value=1 
$b=$value, returing 1. 
$a=1, $b=1 
$value=1 
$a=$value, returing 0. 
$a=2, $b=2 
$value=1 
$value=3 
$value=4 
$value=2 
$a=$value, returing 0.
```

What is the mechanism of creating the 12 $a-$b pairs - 2-1, 2-3, 1-3, 2-4, 3-4, 2-2, 2-1, 2-1 (the same again?), 4-1, 3-1, 1-1, 2-2. The above code returns 1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0. And also what is the mechanism of sorting the array, based on the values that get returned? I am trying to understand how the usort() mechanism works.

Thanks.

Comment: `sort()` uses Quicksort and the docs seem to imply that most other sorts in PHP also use the same algorithm

Comment: [Perhaps this animated explanation of a quicksort might help](http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/)

Comment: There is something wrong with your sorting function.  If two elements have the same sort value it should return 0.  If the first element has a higher sort value then it should return a positive value.  If the second element has a higher sort value then it should return a negative value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **How does the comparator work?**

I'm not sure wether this was part of the question, but to be clear about how the comparator works:
You have an order specified by ordered list `$order` and a special *comparator callback* `list_cmp` which (should) return wether argument

- `$a` is smaller than `$b` (`return -1` or a value `< 0`)
- `$a` greater than `$b` (`return 1` or a value `> 0`)
- `$a` equal `$b` (`return 0`)

`list_cmp` does this by looking up its *order table* and rather checking if

- `$a` has a smaller (or equal) order in which case the loop exits early with `return 0` or if
- `$b` has a smaller order in which case the loop exits early with `return 1`.

*Be aware that this is wrong according to the PHP Documentation which states it wants positive/negative/0 as return values. This is only correct if you know that the internals only check for `comparator($a,$b) > 0`, meaning it only checks if `$b` is smaller than and not equal to `$a`, making this a comparison `order of $a <= order of $b`. It can easily break if the code starts to check for `$a` being smaller than and not equal to `$b`.*

2. **How does the  <s>quicksort</s>  sorting work?**

For starters I'm assuming you are using PHP 7 or higher. In that case you hit a special case with 6-15 Element sized arrays. PHP 7+ does not seem to use quicksort for short lists, instead it uses an Insertion Sort Variant (which is most probably faster due to Hardware related stuff like caching/code locality). You can check the sorting source code f.e. on the [Github PHP Mirror (as an example: PHP 7.0 Zend/Zend_sort.c Line 177-198)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/eac0bf11e4e97916e9688b18e6d62572e12e129f/Zend/zend_sort.c#L176).

The code works in 3 steps:

1. **comparision**: compare neighbor elements `array[j]` and `array[j+1]`, if `array[j] <= array[j+1]` move on, else goto 2.
2. **find insertion point**: now if `array[j] > array[j+1]`, scan backwards to find the point where `array[x] < array[j+1] <= array[x+1]` for `x < j` (obviously only until `x` hits the start)
3. **insert**: shift elements `x+1 ... j` one up such that it becomes `x+2 ... j+1` and insert former element at position `x+1`

If you apply that code to the pairings (2-1, 2-3, 1-3, 2-4, 3-4, 2-2, 2-1, 2-1, 4-1, 3-1, 1-1, 2-2) it gets obvious what the code does.

```
-- [2,1],3,4,2,1,2 -> 1./2./3. compare [2,1], find and insert 1 before 2
-- 1,[2,3],4,2,1,2 -> 1./2. compare [2,3], find insert point for 3 (since order of 3 < order of 2)
-- [1,3],2,4,2,1,2 -> 3. compare [1,3], found insert point for 3 before 2
-- 1,3,[2,4],2,1,2 -> 1./2. compare [2,4], find insert point for 4 (since order of 4 < order of 2) 
-- 1,[3,4],2,2,1,2 -> 3. compare [3,4], found insert point for 4 before 2
-- 1,3,4,[2,2],1,2 -> 1. compare [2,2], skip
-- 1,3,4,2,[2,1],2 -> 1./2. compare [2,1], find insert point for 1
-- 1,3,4,[2,1],2,2 -> 2. compare [2,1], find insert point for 1
-- 1,3,[4,1],2,2,2 -> 2. compare [4,1], find insert point for 1
-- 1,[3,1],4,2,2,2 -> 2. compare [3,1], find insert point for 1
-- [1,1],3,4,2,2,2 -> 3. compare [1,1], fond insert point for 1 before 3
-- 1,1,3,4,2,[2,2] -> 1. compare [2,2], skip
-- sorted: 1,1,3,4,2,2,2
```

PS:
Here you already see that it is quite complex to derive the work of even a simple sorting algorithm (22 lines of code) by its comparison patterns. The PHP 7 quicksort implementation is around 10 times as big in lines of code and has some freaky optimizations (besides normal madness due to pivot selection and recursions).

Most of the times it is better to ignore in depth implementation details and only reduce it to the stuff that is needed. Typical questions for a sorting algorithm would be if it is stable/unstable and performing in `O(log n)` with `O(n)` Memory consumption. There are easier ways to learn the core algorithms behind those optimized implementations like the *Quicksort Dance* or any other visualization or a good old (e)book or webpage with examples.

-- Edited

Added a (bad, unoptimized, unsafe) php implementation for insertion sort for another visualization of how it works:

```
<?php

function my_usort($A, $comparator) {
  // Start .. End Positions
  $current_pos = 0;
  $last_pos = count($A)-1;
  // Outer Loop: each step checks that A[0] up to A[current_pos] is sorted. 
  // When the algorithm finishes we know that A[0] ... A[last_pos] is sorted
  while($current_pos < $last_pos) {
    echo "Sorted Subarray from \$A is " . json_encode(array_slice($A, 0, $current_pos+1)) . "<br>\n";
    echo "\$A looks like this now: " . json_encode($A) . 
    ", comparing [" . $A[$current_pos] . "," . $A[$current_pos +1] . "] (verify step)<br>\n";
    // "Verification Step"
    // At this point A[0] ... A[current_pos] is sorted.
    // Check A[current_pos] <= A[current_pos +1]
    if($comparator($A[$current_pos], $A[$current_pos +1]) > 0) {
      // nope, A[current_pos] > A[current_pos +1] (list_cmp/comparator returns value > 0)
      // "Insertion Step" start, find the correct position for A[current_pos+1] in the already
      // sorted list A[0] ... A[current_pos]
      $insert_point = $current_pos;
      // Swap the missmatching Neighbor pair
      echo "swapping: \$A[" . $insert_point . "] and \$A[" . ($insert_point+1) . "]<br>\n";
      $tmp = $A[$insert_point +1];
      $A[$insert_point +1] = $A[$insert_point];
      $A[$insert_point] = $tmp;
      $sorted_up_to_current_pos = false;
      // Inner Loop: find correct insertion point
      while($insert_point > 0 && !$sorted_up_to_current_pos) {
        echo "\$A looks like this now: " . json_encode($A) . 
        ", comparing [" . $A[$insert_point-1] . "," . $A[$insert_point] . "] (insertion step)<br>\n";
      // "Insertion Step", Swap the missmatching Neighbor pairs until A[0] ... A[current_pos] is sorted again
      if($comparator($A[$insert_point-1], $A[$insert_point]) > 0) {
          // Swap the missmatching Neighbor pair
          echo "swapping: \$A[" . ($insert_point-1) . "] and \$A[" . $insert_point . "]<br>\n";
          $tmp = $A[$insert_point];
          $A[$insert_point] = $A[$insert_point-1];
          $A[$insert_point-1] = $tmp;
          // goto new pair
          $insert_point = $insert_point -1;
        } else {
          // found correct spot, done
          $sorted_up_to_current_pos = true;
        }
      }
      $A[$insert_point] = $tmp;
      echo "\$A looks like this now: " . json_encode($A) . ", insertion done<br>\n";
    }
    $current_pos = $current_pos + 1;
  }
  echo "Sorted Array \$A is " . json_encode(array_slice($A, 0, $current_pos+1)) . "<br>\n";
}

function list_cmp($a, $b) {
  global $order;
  //echo "\$a=$a, \$b=$b </br>\n";

  foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
      //echo "\$value=$value </br>\n";
      if ($a == $value) {
          echo "\$a=\$value, returing 0. </br>\n";
          return 0;
      }
      if ($b == $value) {
          echo "\$b=\$value, returing 1. </br>\n";
          return 1;
      }
  }
}

$order[0] = 1;
$order[1] = 3;
$order[2] = 4;
$order[3] = 2;

$array[0] = 2;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4;
$array[4] = 2;
$array[5] = 1;
$array[6] = 2;

my_usort($array, "list_cmp");
```

Output is complete now with currently sorted array, positions:

```
Sorted Subarray from $A is [2] 
$A looks like this now: [2,1,3,4,2,1,2], comparing [2,1] (verify step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[0] and $A[1] 
$A looks like this now: [1,2,3,4,2,1,2], insertion done 
Sorted Subarray from $A is [1,2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,2,3,4,2,1,2], comparing [2,3] (verify step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[1] and $A[2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,2,4,2,1,2], comparing [1,3] (insertion step) 
$a=$value, returing 0.  
$A looks like this now: [1,3,2,4,2,1,2], insertion done 
Sorted Subarray from $A is [1,3,2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,2,4,2,1,2], comparing [2,4] (verify step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[2] and $A[3] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,4,2,2,1,2], comparing [3,4] (insertion step) 
$a=$value, returing 0.  
$A looks like this now: [1,3,4,2,2,1,2], insertion done 
Sorted Subarray from $A is [1,3,4,2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,4,2,2,1,2], comparing [2,2] (verify step) 
$a=$value, returing 0.  
Sorted Subarray from $A is [1,3,4,2,2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,4,2,2,1,2], comparing [2,1] (verify step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[4] and $A[5] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,4,2,1,2,2], comparing [2,1] (insertion step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[3] and $A[4] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,4,1,2,2,2], comparing [4,1] (insertion step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[2] and $A[3] 
$A looks like this now: [1,3,1,4,2,2,2], comparing [3,1] (insertion step) 
$b=$value, returing 1.  
swapping: $A[1] and $A[2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,1,3,4,2,2,2], comparing [1,1] (insertion step) 
$a=$value, returing 0.  
$A looks like this now: [1,1,3,4,2,2,2], insertion done 
Sorted Subarray from $A is [1,1,3,4,2,2] 
$A looks like this now: [1,1,3,4,2,2,2], comparing [2,2] (verify step) 
$a=$value, returing 0.  
Sorted Array $A is [1,1,3,4,2,2,2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I would not get to this point of knowledge in a week from now or more. Is it correct to say that the array does not change until the sorting process is complete? You depcited the sorting, but when I var_dump the array at certain points of running the code, it is always the same.

Comment: @now_m In the PHP Array Code (for example for ver. 7.0.24) for `usort`/`uasort` and probably other with user callback, there is a [comment about making a copy](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/eac0bf11e4e97916e9688b18e6d62572e12e129f/ext/standard/array.c#L1038) to hide the modifications from the user callback, thats why you don't see modifications. It is not documented thought, so you shouldn't assume anything as it may change with different PHP Versions.

Comment: I am still not getting how this works. There is the $order array and this gets compared to the $a-$b pairs. The only mechanism here is when the list_cmp function returns 1 the current $b value gets moved towards the beginning of the array (lower index; always $b and always this direction). What is "running" the mechanism of finding the right spot for the $b if the list_cmp callback returns 1? This is built in in the usort() and this is how this works? Probably not, since we are not creating something like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, but something like this 1,1,3,4,2,2,2

Comment: @now_m I'm not sure if you have a problem with the algorithm or the whole theory behind sort order. The [algorithmic part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort) is straight forward. All it does is check from the "left" (lowest index) to the "right" (highest index) if each Neighbor pair is in order (and `list_cmp` defines this order). If it hits a pair that doesn't fit (`list_cmp` returns `1`) the right element is shifted to the left and checked again with its new left. This continues until it fits (`list_cmp` returns `0`) or hits the list start. No magic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You seem like a person who is very familiar with that and I am just on the second round of learning the PHP (out of like 10 that I am planning). Thanks again for the explanation. This is the hardest example that I have come across. As you can see, I am still figuring it out, but probably ending it today. Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at the explanation of the 12 lines that you gave. The first line is ok - it checks the first pair, the second line is ok - it goes to the second, following pair. I am not understanding the third line - what makes it go to the first pair again, and the following fourth line (I have not considered the further lines yet) which actually skips one value pair. Lets say that I dont understand how these brackets move? What are the "rules of this"?You said "the right element is shifted to the left and checked again with its new left" but this is now what the above described 1st 4 lines would do

Comment: I know that you gave the exact explanation of steps 1), 2) and 3) and I've been reading and analyzing it since it was answered and this was already 8 days ago. But I am still not getting it at this point. Basically - what are the rules of how these brackets move (I see that "return 1" does the moving of the $b to the left or towards lower index of the array, but what does the moving of these "brackets" here). The brackets, I am meaning here - http://prntscr.com/gq0q7k - Not particularly the two that I highlighted - all the brackets there, every step.

Comment: I am just literally not getting it until this point. I was testing my own examples of usort(), looking at the animations of usort() on the Net and other things like this. I am not just coming in and asking, I've been somehow working on this during these days (this is a secondary task, I do phpStorm doc reading in the mornings as the main task). ;; I know that what I am asking here does not sound like the highest IQ on earth, but I am literally not getting the mechanism yet... And I dont want to leave it like this and move on to the next step.

Comment: It works in pairs - this moves me closer to the understanding, I am sure. But what I am not getting is, lets say, how these brackets move. The first bracket starts at first element - this is ok, the second bracket starts at the second element, and this is ok (it is moving to the right) - the third bracket starts at the first element again, so it is coming back (what makes it come back?), and like I said, the fourth one starts at the third element, so what makes this jump or makes these values get skipped. And like I said, there is 8 more steps. Again, I know it does not sound too smart...

Comment: @now_m The brackets are only a "visualization" of the comparision, each time when `list_cmp` is called by the usort code to check a pair. The algorithm itself is basically an inner and an outer loop. The outer loop "verifies" - in each step - that the Array is sorted up to the current point. The inner loop kicks in when that verification fails and starts to move the "missmatching" element to a fitting position in the already sorted subarray. When the inner loop finishes with the insertion, the outer loop resumes from current position. I've added php implementation, which gives more infos.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time and looking at this. I have like 7 years in all aspects of websites, so if you need something, you can let me know, maybe over Skype. Thanks again.

Comment: So in general the usort() moves from left to right (lowest to highest index). When the list_cmp() callback returns 1 the Insertion Sort implementaion of the PHP looks for the insertion spot going in the opposite direction from the current point (from right to left, starting from the current point). And it is doing that to the point when it finds the right spot. So some of the further steps in this example (8,9,10 as an example) are just that - going right to left in order to find the right insertion spot. And this is basically always based on checking the pairs and returing either 0 or 1.

Comment: I kind of understood that this is how it works from the day one, but I did not fully see it here... I now should have an understanding, but I will look at it again. I will study the code that you added also, several more times. I think that you may be specializing in this and you found it by the "quicksort" and the "usort" tags that I added (I was looking at your other answers too, only like 3 are PHP). I personally was studying a different subject in college (than IT) and things like this are not something that I was learning at any point in my life. But like I said, IT - 7 years of experienc

Comment: Thanks again! So now I see that this going back movement of the brackets is also based on the $order and $a and $b pairs. Again, big thanks. I would not figure this out without your help!!!

Comment: @now_m I took the easy path and studied IT. ;) Beside math and programming fundamentals from other courses, we had a course (half-year, about 8 hours a week and homework) about basic Data-structures and Algorithms like Sorting, the principle of "Divide and Conquer", Lists/Tree Data-structures, proving correctness and complexity in terms of runtime/memory. I can only imagine how hard that is in pure self-study. Not to get too Off-Topic: That course is often called "Introduction to Algorithms", you may want to check that out. Beside some (expensive) books, there are lots of free web resources.