# What is the mechanism of ordering this array with usort()?

Tags: php, sorting, insertion-sort, usort

```
<?php
function list_cmp($a, $b) {
    global $order;

    foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
        if ($a == $value) {
            return 0;
        }

        if ($b == $value) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

$order[0] = 1;
$order[1] = 3;
$order[2] = 4;
$order[3] = 2;

$array[0] = 2;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4;
$array[4] = 2;
$array[5] = 1;
$array[6] = 2;

usort($array, "list_cmp");
```

I know that this is Insertion Sort (not a Quicksort, since the array is 6-15 elements large). I see that the $a-$b pairs get compared to the order and if the list_cmp callback function returns 1, the current $b value gets moved towards the beginning of the array. This is how the usort() works, only the $b gets moved. I am assuming that it is always in this direction and that this assumption is correct.

The $a-$b pairs are like this - 2-1, 2-3, 1-3, 2-4, 3-4, 2-2, 2-1, 2-1, 4-1, 3-1, 1-1, 2-2, and these are the values that get returned in all the steps - 1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0 (if 1 is returned the $b gets moved and if 0 is returned I guess the usort() is looking for the correct insertion spot, but how this works? I am not seeing how this works, what or where is the mechanism of this?)

I know that it is 1) comparing 2) finding an insertion point and 3) inserting and that it looks like this:

```
-- [2,1],3,4,2,1,2 -> 1./2./3. compare [2,1], find and insert 1 before 2
-- 1,[2,3],4,2,1,2 -> 1./2. compare [2,3], find insert point for 3 (since order of 3 < order of 2)
-- [1,3],2,4,2,1,2 -> 3. compare [1,3], found insert point for 3 before 2
-- 1,3,[2,4],2,1,2 -> 1./2. compare [2,4], find insert point for 4 (since order of 4 < order of 2) 
-- 1,[3,4],2,2,1,2 -> 3. compare [3,4], found insert point for 4 before 2
-- 1,3,4,[2,2],1,2 -> 1. compare [2,2], skip
-- 1,3,4,2,[2,1],2 -> 1./2. compare [2,1], find insert point for 1
-- 1,3,4,[2,1],2,2 -> 2. compare [2,1], find insert point for 1
-- 1,3,[4,1],2,2,2 -> 2. compare [4,1], find insert point for 1
-- 1,[3,1],4,2,2,2 -> 2. compare [3,1], find insert point for 1
-- [1,1],3,4,2,2,2 -> 3. compare [1,1], fond insert point for 1 before 3
-- 1,1,3,4,2,[2,2] -> 1. compare [2,2], skip
-- sorted: 1,1,3,4,2,2,2
```

But again, I am basically not seeing a mechanism of finding the insertion spots. The dynamic of this is - list_cmp returns 1 - move the $b (and towards the beginning of the array), but what is the mechanism of finding the right spot? One could say, this is within the usort() but we are not generating something like puttting 5 here 1,2,3,4,x,6,7,8,9. The result of this is 1,1,3,4,2,2,2 and this is based on whats within the $order array.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? I don't really understand. To me it looks like the `usort()` is putting the elements in the right order, since `$order` has `[1, 3, 4, 2]` and you're ending up with `[1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2]`

Comment: I am not seeing how this gets done. I am only seeing that returning 1 from list_cmp moves the $b (this is how the usort() works). I am not seeing / understanding the mechanism of ordering it into 1,1,3,4,2,2,2 (I know that this is based on the order within the $order array). The explanation of how this works. Like a math task that you dont understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php states:

> **value_compare_func**
>   The comparison function must return an integer less
>   than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is
>   considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the
>   second

When you call the function, it takes any two values and decides whether they're in the right order.

Really all it does is move `$b` variable up or down the array in respect to `$a`.

Adding some output to your function can show you what's going on:

```
<?php
function list_cmp($a, $b) {
    global $order;

    echo "comparing $a and $b...\n";
    foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
        echo "  checking against $value\n";
        if ($a == $value) {
            echo "    \$a ($a) == $value: returning 0\n";
            return 0;
        }

        if ($b == $value) {
            echo "    \$b  ($b) == $value: returning 1\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's look at the first part of the output:

```
comparing 4 and 1...
  checking against 1
    $b  (1) == 1: returning 1
```

Here you can see that it's checking the two values 4 and 1 (we don't know which 1 it is). It then checks each item in `$order`. The first value is 1, which is saying all the 1s must come before any other value.

`$a` doesn't match 1 but `$b` does. So these items are in the wrong order - the first item is *greater than* the second, so we return 1. i.e. 4 must come after 1.

Let's look at another bit of output:

```
comparing 4 and 2...
  checking against 1
  checking against 3
  checking against 4
    $a (4) == 4: returning 0
```

Here it has checked the values 1 and 3 - neither of them match the two numbers we're considering, so they're irrelevant.  Then we get to `$a` (4). That equals the next wanted value. This means it's in the right place, so we return 0. i.e. 4 must come before 2 - and it does.

That continues for each pair the sort compares.

Comment: What's the point of quoting from the documentation about the custom comparison function that must return a negative value when several lines below you post the wrong comparison function from the question that returns `0` instead of negative values?

Comment: @axiac I used the question answerer's function as presented; and there's no need to return -1 in any case because that's not how the comparison works in this instance. This doesn't make a _direct_ comparison between two values, it just checks whether they are comparatively in the right place with respect to separate ordering cirteria.

Comment: @DarenChandisingh - Thanks for the info. Check out the link below, which contains a good explanation of this ("46274723" in the url). It is known what "1" gets checked, what are the individual steps and so on. I am not a pro yet but this seems like a good edu example, I think. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your custom comparison function is incorrect. It must return a negative value when `$a` must stay in front of `$b` in the sorted array, zero (`0`) when `$a` and `$b` are equal and a positive value when `$a` must stay after `$b` in the sorted array.

If you read *"`$a` is smaller than `$b`"* instead of *"`$a` stays before `$b`"* (and *"greater"* instead of *"after"*) you get the array sorted ascending. But nobody says the array must be sorted ascending and there is no custom array sorting function for descending sorting. The order of the elements in the final array is decided by the custom comparison function provided.

You are talking about "insertion points" in the question. There are dozens of sorting algorithms. Some of them start with an empty list and insert the elements in their final positions, others swap two items and do the sorting in-place.

I don't know what algorithm is implemented by the [`u*sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) PHP functions (and for the daily use I don't even care) but I assume it uses [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or other fast algorithm. Just for your curiosity, quicksort doesn't insert anything, it swaps items.

No matter what algorithm is used, the main operation used by sorting is the comparison of two items. How the algorithm uses the items after it finds out which one should stay in front of the other is a different story but it doesn't interfere with the comparison itself.

Comment: This is Insertion Sort since the array is 6-15 items in size. I know that the code is not correct according to the specification but it can be said that for this example it works as it should.

Comment: Just for my curiosity, do you have a reference for this assertion about the sorting algorithm?

Comment: The comparison function is broken, anyway: https://3v4l.org/mZnD2. `list_cmp(1, 3)` should return `-1`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works

Comment: Oh, you have posted the same question before. You have got an answer, you have got accepted it but have you read it? Apparently not.

Comment: I've read this answer multiple times and this has been the base of what I've been doing regarding this example since like 5 or 7 days. I am just not getting it yet and this is the hardest out of the examples that I've been working on so far (w3resource.com PHP exercises). I asked again because I was stuck on it for like five days at this point (but I only do this in the afternoon, I do phpStorm doc reading as the main thing, during this second learning round <I am a beginner, I am learning the PHP>).