# What is the reason of returning -1 instead of lets say 0 at the end of this function's code?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach, usort

I am talking about the second "return -1;" on the 12th line of the code. This gets reached only if two sets of numbers are exactly the same, like when comparing '192.167.11' to '192.167.11'. I will also add that using range(0,2) would be a better option for this piece of code (range(0,3) produces errors if two elements happen to be the same; I did not change that as this is the original code example from PHP Array Exercise #21 from w3resource.com).

```
<?php
function sort_subnets($x, $y){
    $x_arr = explode('.', $x);
    $y_arr = explode('.', $y);
    foreach (range(0, 3) as $i) {
        if ($x_arr[$i] < $y_arr[$i]) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($x_arr[$i] > $y_arr[$i]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

$subnet_list =
    array('192.169.12',
        '192.167.11',
        '192.169.14',
        '192.168.13',
        '192.167.12',
        '122.169.15',
        '192.167.16'
    );
usort($subnet_list, 'sort_subnets');
print_r($subnet_list);
?>
```

Returning "-1" would move the second element (the same as the first in the current $x and $y pair) towards the higher index of the array (down the array). Why not return "0" and keep everything as is if the two elements are exactly the same? Is there any reason for returning the "-1" maybe based on how the usort() works (or any other factor of this)?

Thanks.

#### EDIT:

I think that this is Insertion Sort (array size 6-15 elements; normally it would be Quicksort).

Comment: 0 means no difference. -1 stats the number is smaller.  its indeed how the function usort works... side note it's wierd the function ip2long (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) isn't been used in the code.

Comment: Actually, I agree with @now_m. If the subnets are identical, the function *should* return `0` instead of `-1`, since the sort order shouldn't change for identical values.

Comment: For the sorting functions: -1 means before, 0 means equal, +1 means after. May not be relevant in most cases, but some sorting algorithms can benefit from order context. The last return should rather be 0 in this sample code. (Again, wouldn't matter very much here.)

Comment: The whole foreach part isn't really necessary anyway. You can just compare the arrays directly. `$x_arr <=> $y_arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two elements are the same, there's no difference between swapping the order and keeping the order the same. So it doesn't make a difference what it returns in that case.

You're right that `0` is more appropriate. This would be more important if `usort` were "stable". But the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) says

> **Note:**
>   If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.

Comment: I think that returning "0" or "-1" may produce different scenario for the further usort() steps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works ; I am not sure if this is the case, but it may not be the same thing.

Comment: As far as I remember if $x and $y are swapped the usort() comes back towards the beginning of the array to make sure that everything is in order up to the current point. If they would not get swapped it would continue in the normal direction from the current point. For this reason I was wondering if there is a logic or intention behind the second "-1" or probably not? I am on a beginner level and I am learning the php. I am not skipping over things like this and I want to get to the bottom of the examples from the w3resource.com (for now).

Comment: It depends on whether the sorting algorithm assumes the comparison is transitive. I couldn't really tell from that answer.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the excellent point of @Don'tPanic:

```
<?php
function sort_subnets($x, $y){
    $x_arr = explode('.', $x);
    $y_arr = explode('.', $y);
    return $x_arr <=> $y_arr;
}

$subnet_list =
    array('192.169.12',
        '192.167.11',
        '192.169.14',
        '192.168.13',
        '192.167.12',
        '122.169.15',
        '192.167.16'
    );
usort($subnet_list, 'sort_subnets');
print_r($subnet_list);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/iFGrp#output)

Note the use of the "spaceship" operator, namely `<=>` which offers a conciseness that spares one from having to write code like the following in a function:

```
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
```

Lastly, note that the user-defined callback for usort() makes use of *[ternary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)* because sometimes as in the case of sorting [bivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence) logic is insufficient.  Yet, [usort()](http://php.net/usort) itself utilizes two-part logic, returning TRUE on success and FALSE on failure.

Comment: (This may be inconsequential for the OP, but is worth mentioning for readers...) Note that the example `sort_subnets()` function may exhibit surprising behaviour when the values have differing numbers of subnets (i.e. different lengths of arrays).  For example, any exploded value with two items will be sorted as "less than" any with three items (more generally, arrays of different lengths will display this behaviour), which might come as a surprise given the intended purpose of this function.