# Does returning "-1" with usort really move the $b variable or does it keep it in the same place?

Tags: php, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort, usort

A simple piece of code written by me:

```
<?php
function testing($a,$b){
    if ($a < $b ){
        return -1;
    }
    elseif ($a > $b){
        return 1;
    }
    //else {
        //return 0;
    //}
}

$array = array(1,3,2,4,5);
usort($array, "testing");
var_dump($array);
?>
```

This is from the top comment (highest rated comment and from 5 years ago) on the php.net manual's usort page:

"If you return -1 that moves the $b variable down the array, return 1 moves $b up the array and return 0 keeps $b in the same place."

As far as I was looking at the piece of code that I've written returning "-1" does not move the $b, it stays in the same place. It is only the "return 1;" statement that moves the $b (as compared to the $a, current $a-$b) pair.

Lets say we have something like this:
[1,3],2,4,5 - Return -1

The square brackets indicate the current $a-$b pair. Would we get something like this: 
1,2,3,4,5
 ,meaning the $b would be switched with the following element which is out of the current $a-$b pair?
The point here is that I think that it is only the current $a-$b elements that can get switched. And with this the "return -1;" statement does not do any moving, which is not how I was thinking this works.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. `-1`, `0` or `1` indicates to `usort` which element is greater or whether both are equal. The result of the entire `usort` operation will be an array sorted according to that information. What exactly happens during each individual step is rather irrelevant and subject to change as the specific `usort` implementation may change.

Comment: It is not possible to see how the sorted array looks in the middle of the process. You can see the current $a-$b pairs after adding echo statements to the code. I am trying to understand how the process works "under the hood" just like I did with the example here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works Returning "-1" was not part of the equation here, and now I see that it does not actually do the moving (or maybe I am wrong?).

Comment: You could try with an anonymous function referencing the array (`usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($arr) { ... })`) and output the array every step of the way too… I'm not sure whether the result would be reflected immediately or not though. You could also study the PHP source code to see how it works exactly. I'm just questioning what good that really does you.

Comment: I was basically thinking, based on the comment on the usort() manual on the php.net that -1 moves the $b in one direction, 1 in the opposite direction and 0 (as a return value of the callback function, this is what I am taling about) keeps it in the same place. But this is not correct, only return 1 moves the $b and it can only get moved towards the beginning of the array (switched with the $a before it in the current order of things). So return -1 is the same as return 0 here?

Comment: The logic of usort() actually changed between PHP5 and PHP7, to make it a lot more efficient with a lot fewer comparisons; but it's still basically using a quicksort algorithm.... [echoing the "pairs" that are being compared inside the callback function](https://3v4l.org/c2QeT) can be quite interesting

Comment: @deceze - Would you be able to write a code that uses an anonymous function or a closure that would enable me to view the stages of the sorting of the array. I was trying to and I am not sure if this is a doable thing. Or maybe some other person reading this.

Comment: Another comment - Would this be correct to say if an array contains 6-15 elements the PHP (lets say we are talking about version 7) uses Insertion Sort and if it is like in this example 5 elements, it would be Quicksort. So this particular example code would work on Quicksort. I think that this can be taken from here (I am not on the level of figuring this out yet, or it would take me too much time) - https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/eac0bf11e4e97916e9688b18e6d62572e12e129f/Zend/zend_sort.c#L177

Comment: Basically I am still trying to see how this particular sorting works "under the hood". I have not been able to achieve this yet.