# Is it possible to see the stages of sorting an array with usort with a custom written php code?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

Lets say any array but it can be applying only to this piece of code. Based on the info from here I know that if there is 6-15 elements in an array the sorting algorithm used would be Insertion Sort and for other number of elements it would be the Quicksort:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/eac0bf11e4e97916e9688b18e6d62572e12e129f/Zend/zend_sort.c#L176

```
<?php
function testing($a,$b){
    if ($a < $b ){
        return -1;
    }
    elseif ($a > $b){
        return 1;
    }
    //else {
        //return 0;
    //}
}

$array = array(1,3,2,4,5);
usort($array, "testing");
var_dump($array);
?>
```

People have been saying that I am overthinking this and that this is not needed, but seeing every stage of sorting the array would be the best representation of how the algorithm works (it is not that easy to figure this out from the $a-$b pairs that I can output with echo or something like that). var_dump will not show me the stages of sorting an array, it will be always the same.

Again, this is the only goal of this question - achieve the access to viewing the stages of sorting (any / an) array.

Somebody has suggested something like this but I have not been able to figure this out, it may not be a doable thing:

"You could try with an anonymous function referencing the array (usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($arr) { ... })) and output the array every step of the way too… I'm not sure whether the result would be reflected immediately or not though."

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't I provide a link to show the values of each call when I answered [your  previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547848/does-returning-1-with-usort-really-move-the-b-variable-or-does-it-keep-it-in)?

Comment: [This animation](http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/) might also help you understand

Comment: @MarkBaker - The link was to showing the $a-$b pairs and I am looking for all the stages of the array. I was using the $a-$b pairs output since some time ago. Like I said, this gives some info on what is going on but the best insight would be from seeing the stages of sorting the array. I am not sure if this is accessible or only accessible with custom written php code that would be based on the php's source code (php implementation of php source code for usort()).

Comment: I want to try different scenarios to make sure I understand how the usort() behaves. The callback function can return negative, 0, positive and only the $b value in a current pair gets moved. I realized that returning -1 does not move the $b so this is like returning 0, but I am not sure. I would like to compare like 3 or 10 different scenarios to understand how this works. Seeing all the stages of sorting any array would be a perfect thing for what I am trying to do, and I am not sure if this is a doable thing (except for php implementation of the php source code for usort, this can be done)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fv8tuxr0 - I created this as an example, and what gets output is included there. It creates regular $a-$b pairs and when the last before the last element is not fitting the order it comes back towards the beginning of the array by skipping every other value, and I am not sure why - the pairs created look like this - 9-2, 7-2, 5-2, 3-2, 2-1 - I mean it would not be comparing 8-2, 6-2 or 4-2 on its way towards the beginning of the array. Different behavior for different sets and numbers of the (inside an array) values.

Comment: You can't get much more from PHP.... if you want more detail of how it works internally, then you'll have to do it through the underlying C code that implements the sort functions for PHP.... but try to understand how a quicksort algorithm actually works first, there's a myriad of pages on the web (such as the one with animations that I linked in my previous comment) that describe the mechanics of the algorithm.... you can even work it through with paper and pencil

Comment: @MarkBaker - Thanks, I am familair with the animations and I was looking at them before, when I was working on one of my previous questions, which was also related to the usort() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works ; Being able to see the stages of sorting the array would be the best thing edu wise, but I guess it is not something that can be done. At this point it is good for me to know that it cant be done from the php level and I can continue working on this in some other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

A copy of the input array is created in usort, so you won't be able to observe what it's doing via PHP code.

See in the [PHP source code for usort](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/32e8e16304250baa55bcdf62b41a4048250863a8/ext/standard/array.c#L1048):

```
/* Copy array, so the in-place modifications will not be visible to the callback function */
arr = zend_array_dup(arr);
```