# Will $a > $b ever break usort() with an array of integers?

Tags: php, sorting

In almost every example of `usort()` the logic seems to be that you should return -1, 0, or 1, making the new spaceship operator ideal.  Before php7 the most basic example goes like this:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding why not simply use:

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a > $b;
}
```

Will this ever break and if so under what conditions?

I've also read [How the usort() sorting algorithm works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works), compared results from both methods outlined above for the life of me I can't understand why the suggested method will ever return a different result.

Comment: `return $a > $b;` returns a boolean, not a number.

Comment: I understand, but will it change the sorting behaviour?  Ever?

Comment: It depends on the actual implementation of `usort`. If it only relies on the inequality (on its greater value) - it would work. If it uses equality or less inequality it would break. Given that `usort` documentation does not guarantee one or another implementation it's safe to assume that the `return $a > $b;` implementation is invalid.

Comment: @zerkms according to docs, returning `0` will result in no sorting action - and as far as I am aware that goes for all implementations of `usort()`.  If this is the case, when would it ever sort the array differently?  I think I understand what you are saying but it still doesn't answer my question.  When, how and under what conditions would `$a > $b` produce a different result?

Comment: You can implement a sorting function that only uses `0` and `-1` values. And your function does not return those.

Comment: If you want to simplify the logic and still obey the rules, you can use `return $a - $b`. Only the sign of the result matters, it doesn't have to be specifically `-1` or `1`.

Comment: @Barmar - yes I was using that in a broader context and got into trouble where floats were involved.  It was that trouble that led me to question of why `$a > $b` wasn't a more popular option.  At this point I'm going to use `<=>` and call it a day but it's been interesting learning about the mechanics of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current sorting implementation used in `usort` can be found here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ba298725d194f753c0220bd9ac482e3d257a9ddc/Zend/zend_sort.c#L317

As you can see it only uses the `> 0` comparison, eg

```
while (cmp(pivot, i) > 0) {
```

If php core team for some reason changes the implementation to use `== 0` or `< 0`, then your solution would break (because it does not differentiate between those cases).

Given that documentation makes no claims on how the sorting would ever be implemented - it's safe to assume that every function that does not follow the protocol - is incorrect and is not guaranteed to work.

In general - for unstable sorting just "whether $a is greater than $b" is enough. Some programming languages/libraries employ it. Eg: in Go you only need to implement a simple `Less` function that returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

The statement
return $a > $b;
Is equal to
If ($a > $b) return 1; else return 0;
Because any returned type other than integer will be casted to integer value.
In simplest way your code provide ascending order only.
Maybe this code will be fail intentionally if usort is implemented with the fastest algorithm. Until this time I think that usort compare each element with all other elements, and you need only [0, 1] for ASC order, [0, -1] for DESC order.