# whice value get in a callback function in usort() in php?

Tags: php, arrays, usort

```
function so($a, $b) {
        if($a == $b) {
                return 0;
        } 
         else {
                return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
        }
}

$num = [5,3,2,1,4];
usort($num, 'so');
foreach($num as $value) {
        echo $value." ";
}
```

I write this code and the result is 1,2,3,4,5 and it is good! But I don't understand how this usort function actually work. I even don't understand what value $a and $b get to return 0, 1 or -1 can anyone explain me it?

Comment: from [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) _The comparison function (e.g. `so` in your case) must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second._ Does that clear you on the 0, -1 and 1 returned by callback `so()`? Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274723/how-the-usort-sorting-algorithm-works)

Answer (score 0):

Print your result in so() function then you got your answer.
when usort() called it compare values with each other and return response in the form of integers 0, 1 and -1.
On the basis of that result sorting take place

```
function so($a, $b) {
    if($a == $b) {
        echo $value = 0;
            return $value;
    } 
     else {
        $value = $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
        echo $value;
        return $value;
    }
}

$num = [5,3,2,1,4];

usort($num, 'so');

foreach($num as $value) {
    echo $value." ";
}
```